# How to sum a virtual column from children association ? (Sequelize)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 objects (A, B and C) linked together. I can have multiple B associated to A and multiple C associated to B. Like for example:

```
A
└───B
│   └───C   
│   └───C
└───B
    └───C
```

In C I have 2 duration (`xDuration` and `yDuration`) and I created a virtual column `totalDuration`.

I want to have in each object the total duration of all children. For example if B has two children C with respectively 20 and 40 min, my total duration in B will be 60 and so on.

Here are my objects definitions:

`A.model.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    const A = sequelize.define("A", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
    });

    A.associate = function(models) {
        A.hasMany(models.B, {
            foreignKey: "AId",
            sourceKey: "id",
        });
    };

    return A;
};
```

`B.model.js`

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    const B = sequelize.define("B", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
        AId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    });

    B.associate = function(models) {
        B.belongsTo(models.A, {
            foreignKey: "AId",
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
        });

        B.hasMany(models.C, {
            foreignKey: "BId",
        });
    };

    return B;
};
```

`C.model.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    const C = sequelize.define("C", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
        BId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        xDuration: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: () => 0,
        },
        yDuration: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: () => 0,
        },
        totalDuration: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
            get: function() {
                return this.get("xDuration") + this.get("yDuration");
            },
        },
    });

    C.associate = function(models) {
        C.belongsTo(models.B, {
            foreignKey: "BId",
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
        });
    };

    return C;
};
```

NPM modules versions:

- **Sequelize:** 6.21.3
- **pg:** 8.7.3

I tried create a virtual column for each in the definition but I can't access the children from there.

The almost working solution I tried was to add an attribute in my `findAll()` with something like this :

```js
B.findAll({
    attributes: [
        [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('C.totalDuration')), 'totalDuration'],
    ],
    include: [
        {
            model: C,
            attributes: ["totalDuration"]
        }
    ],
    group: ['C.id'],
});
```

But since `totalDuration` does not exist, it's only a virtual column, I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plain SQL subquery to calculate the sum for all children like this:

```js
B.findAll({
    attributes: [
        [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT SUM(C.xDuration + C.yDuration) FROM C WHERE C.BId=B.id)'), 'totalDuration'],
    ],
});
```